# Change table class in mobile view?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap` and I would like my table to have the `table-condensed` class applied in mobile view, and `table-responsive` class applied above mobile size.

What is the best approach to that? Is there a way to do this in `SASS`?

I have just stumbled across '`extend`' in `SASS` but I don't think it is quite what I need as when I tried to implement it, I couldn't use it within my media query, outside of the media query worked ok

Thank you :)

(I am working on trying to include my code but I am getting an error)

Comment: Even if someone could point me in the direction of some keywords to search for I will greatly appreciate it, I think my problem is I am not searching for the the right keywords / phrases to get the answer I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery resize function

example

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
 var screenwidth = $(document).width();
 if(screewidth <= 480)
 {
  $("#table").removeClass("table-responsive");
  $("#table").addClass("table-condensed");
 }
 else
 {
  $("#table").removeClass("table-condensed");
  $("#table").addClass("table-responsive");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SASS you can specify the properties of the table when in mobile using media queries:

[SASS](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32):

```
$break-small: 320px;
$break-large: 1200px;
.table {
  //Default table properties
  @media screen and (max-width: $break-small) {
    //small screen size table properties
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: $break-large) {
    //Large screen size table properties
  }
}
```

If you are using [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):

```
table{
   //Regular table properties
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    //small screen size table properties
}
```